# how can I set the converter binding in the C# code?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpftoolkit

I am newbie in WPF and now I am using a 3rd party lib xamChart in my project

previously in the XAML i have a Chart and its axis has a **Unit which is a int** property
and I have

```
Unit="{Binding NextStartRow, Converter={StaticResource UnitConverter}}"
```

This works perfectly, but now I need to create the chart in the runtime through the code behind.
How can I do that in C#?  and FYI all the axis.Unit.xxx in the c# code do not have the thing I want, Please help, thank you very much in advance, any suggestion is much appreciated!

FYI code snippet in of xaml

```
<igCA:Axis AxisType="PrimaryX" AutoRange="True"  
           Unit="{Binding AnotherIntegerProperty, Converter={StaticResource UnitConverter}}">
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try this by adjusting anything is not correct as you missed to specify:

```
myXamChart.SetBinding(
  Unit,
  new Binding("AnotherIntegerProperty")
  {
    Converter = new UnitConverter()
  });
```

Cheers